# Vue.js with vuex and axios - can get data only on second load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

I created a Vue.js app with a central store with vuex and some basic API calls with axios to fetch data into the store.

I create the following store action:

```
  loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament({commit}, {parliament_id, area_code}) {
    axios.get('/cc-api/area-code/' + parliament_id + '/' + area_code)
         .then((response) => {
           commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', response.data);
         })
         .catch(function(error){
           commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', null);
          }
         )
  }
```

In a single component file I defined a form where the user enters the area code. This form then calls this action to get the constituency fitting the area code:

```
export default {
  name: 'AreaCodeForm',
  components: {
    PostalCodeInput
  },
  props: ['parliament_id'],
  data: () => ({
    postalCode: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    search_area_code(submitEvent) {
      let area_code = submitEvent.target.elements.area_code.value;
      let payload = {
        parliament_id: this.parliament_id,
        area_code
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament', payload).
          then(() => {
        let constituency = this.$store.getters.getConstituency();
        // do some things with the data received from the API
        // but everything depending on constituency does not work the first time.
        // Data received from the API is here available only from the second time on
        // wehen this code run.
      })
    }
  }
}
```

As I found out the `$store.dispatch` method returns a promise but still the `constituency` variable receives not the data fetched with the `loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament` action but remains empty. I thought when I use the `promise.then` method the data should be already stored in the store but it is not. When I enter the area code a second time everything works well.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the `axios.get` call (right now, it's just a "fire & forget" promise)

Comment: Try to avoid using the action promise response directly as it violates some of the core paradigm of one-way data flow.  The action should set some data in Vuex, the getter changes accordingly, and you simply use that getter in your component.  In other words, use `mapGetters` rather than imperatively setting `constituency`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by blex in a comment returning the axios call is the answer:

```
  loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament({commit}, {parliament_id, area_code}) {
    return axios.get('/cc-api/area-code/' + parliament_id + '/' + area_code)
         .then((response) => {
           commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', response.data);
         })
         .catch(function(error){
           commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', null);
          }
         )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember the `return` statement when dealing with asyncronous tasks.
You have two options to refactorize your code, keeping `promise` or `async/await`.

### **Option 1: `async/await`**

---

```js
async loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament({ commit }, { parliament_id, area_code }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios('/cc-api/area-code/' + parliament_id + '/' + area_code)
      commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', data)
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', null)
      return error
    }
  }
```

**Notes**:

- `return` statement in both blocks of `try/catch`.
- `.get` in axios is optional, since default is `get` method.
- You can use object Destructuring assignment with `{ data }` by default with axios. If I'm not wrong the default good http responses retrieve data.
  Even a more sophisticated way could be `const { data: constituencyResponse } = await...` then you work with constituencyResponse and you probably save 2 or 3 lines of code each time.

### Option 2: `Promise`

---

#### First Path: Make everything in the store.

```js
 // actions
loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament({ commit, dispatch }, { parliament_id, area_code }) {
  axios('/cc-api/area-code/' + parliament_id + '/' + area_code)
    .then(({data}) => {
      commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', data)
      dispatch('actionTwo', constituency)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error", error)
      commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', null)
    })
}

actionTwo({commit}, constituency) {
  console.log("actionTwo", constituency)
  // do something
  commit('COMMIT', 'Final value')
}
```

```js
// Component
// You handle it with a computed property either referencing a getter or the store state.

{
  computed: {
    getConstituency(){
      return this.$store.state.constituency
    },
    getSomeOtherConstituency(){
      return this.$store.state.constituency.something / 3
    }
  },

  // Optionally if you want to listen and react to changes use a `watcher`.
  watch: {
    // Gets excecuted each time getConstituency updates.
    // ! Must have the same name.
    getConstituency(update) {
      // Do something, `update` is the new value.
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Second Path: Handle data inside the component, then update the store.

<sup>Vue component</sup>.

```js
methods: {
 search_area_code(submitEvent) {
    const parliament_id = this.parliament_id
    const area_code = submitEvent.target.elements.area_code.value

    axios('/cc-api/area-code/' + parliament_id + '/' + area_code)
      .then(({data: constituency}) => {
          this.$store.commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', constituency)
          // Do whatever you want with constituency now inside the component.
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error)
        this.$store.commit('SET_CONSTITUENCY', null)
      })
  }
},
```

**Notes:**

> **$store.dispatch method returns a promise** but still the constituency variable receives not the data fetched with the loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament action but remains empty.
> **When I enter the area code a second time everything works well.**

I think the problem here is that you either handled bad the asyncronous code or trying to implement a custom pattern to work around.

As I said earlier put store getters in computed properties,
Look at this example in the [Vuex-docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access).

**Code insights:**

```js
// Your action doesn't return anything, you must `return axios.get` inside it.
this.$store.dispatch('loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament', payload).then(() => {
  let constituency = this.$store.getters.getConstituency()
})

// without the `return` statement the code above can be translated to
this.$store.dispatch('loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament', payload)
let constituency = this.$store.getters.getConstituency()

// If you opt for async a valid way would be
async doSomething(){
  await this.$store.dispatch('loadConstituencyByAreaCodeAndParliament', payload)
  let constituency = this.$store.getters.getConstituency()
}

// IF it still doesnt update anything try `$nextTick` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/

this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.data = this.$store.getters.getConstituency()     
})
```

I hope some of this has been helpful.